# Excel/VBA iterate over cells in a column get eMail from cell, validate and send automatic Notification

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create an Excel file where people can enter their E-Mail address and as soon as 5 People added their E-Mail an Message is sent to all those E-Mails.

To execute the VBA-Makro when saving i do the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'My Code is here
End Sub
```

I try to loop over one column but didn't found a good solution for this - currently I have set a Rage from B2 to B99
I need to get the E-Mail from the cell, ignore empty/null cells and I need to somehow check the E-Mail if its valid (RegEx?)

```
Dim eMailList As String
Dim eMailCount As Integer

eMailCount = 0
eMailList = ""

Dim eMail As String

Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B2:B99")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    eMail = rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="B").Text
eMailList = eMailList & eMail & "; "
Next


Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    With objMail
        .To = eMailList
        .Subject = "DummyText"
        .Body = "DummyText"
        .send
    End With
```

My Questions are:

1. How can I easy iterate over the cells in one specific Column?
2. How can I get the eMail from the cell - .Text .Value?
3. How to use Regular Expressions in VBA/Excel to validate Email?
4. How can I list the EMails and send a message to each E-Mail

Im glad for any help/tip/recommendation
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please only ask 1 question at a time. And if you do a search for all your sepreate issues you should find plenty answers.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will get you started, explanations inside the codes comments:

```
Dim Rng As Range, C As Range

Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B2:B99")
' loop through all cells in Range (Column "B")
For Each C In Rng
    If Trim(C.Value2) <> "" Then ' <-- check that cell isn't empty
        ' --- Add Here another IF criteria to validate your E-Mail ---

        eMail = Rng.Value2 ' <-- read the value2 of the cell (without the cell's format)
        eMailList = eMailList & eMail & "; "
    End If
Next C
```